# Captcha Code Case Sensitiveness in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

How to Set Captcha Code in Uppercase. Are their any more help for captcha other than codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

To create a captcha with uppercase characters you'd need to do something like this:

```
$vals = array(
    'word' => strtoupper('Random word'), // Here is where the captcha code is converted to uppercase
    'img_path' => './captcha/',
    'img_url' => 'http://example.com/captcha/',
    'font_path' => './path/to/fonts/texb.ttf',
    'img_width' => '150',
    'img_height' => 30,
    'expiration' => 7200
    );

$cap = create_captcha($vals);
echo $cap['image'];
```

Of course you may need to check SQL when checking and make it look into checking for the uppercase version of your random word in the database.

Comment: **Thorpe Obazee:**
Thank you for the reminding me strtoupper function in php. I forgot it

Answer (score 1):

One method is to change Collation of captcha word field in captcha table to latin1_general_cs .

Answer (score 0):

The really easy fix/work-around is to use a font that is all caps.

You can find such a font from http://www.myfonts.com and pay a few dollars for a web license and get a font that you like.

Search for "all caps" or similar.

Alternatively, you can search the web and find a free font.

This is easier than trying to hack into the CodeIgniter CAPTCHA Helper.

Comment: **Marc Audet:**
Thanks for Showing me fonts sites